# php regular expression find number and append area code to it

Tags: php, regex

I have string like this

some string with in which a number pattern 3-9485 may come multiple times like this this another number 9-8465, its pattern is a number and minus and 4 numbers

I tried

```
$str="sdf sdf sd fsd f sdf ds fds fsd f dss2 fsd fsd 3-9776 sdf sd fsd sdf";
$str = preg_replace("/^[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4}$/",'99',$str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is looking for the string to only be the pattern.  The `^` is for the start of the string and the `$` is for the end of the string.

Use `\b` to show that the pattern should be its own word. This tells the pattern that there should be a word boundary at this location (a space, end of string, or beginning of the string)

```
$str = preg_replace("/\b([0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4})\b/",'{$1}99',$str);
```

Comment: it is replacing the while number with 99, I want to append 99 to the number

Comment: Change it to use a capturing group and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern is looking for a full match as you're including the assertions `^` and `$`. It will only match the string if it contains only the hyphen-separated number. Also, note that you need to capture this number to be able to append it with 99.

```
$str = preg_replace("/([0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4})/", '${1}99', $str);
                      ^--   capture   --^     ^^^^-- backreference
```

This will match the part of a string if it contains the pattern. If you want it to only match if the pattern exists on its own (i.e. separated by spaces), you can add [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to the regex. Roughly speaking, a word boundary is a place between a word character (`\w`) and a non-word character (`\W`). This isn't true for all the dialects, though.

The updated regular expression becomes:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\b([0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4})\b/", '{$1}99', $str);
```

Cleaning up a bit, this can be shortened to:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\b(\d-\d{4})\b/", '${1}99', $str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133282)

Comment: Just an FYI: This pattern will also match all parts of the string that contain the pattern.  Like aa9-1234bbb

Comment: @Schleis: Nice catch. Updated my answer to reflect this.